# not able to set ID's to dynamically created labels in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

i created a label dynamically in jquery. I need to assign certain styles to that label. Here i tried to assign a unique ID to that label and apply styles. But it's not working.

my code is;

**Javascript**

```
var lbl = $("<label>").text('Welcome');
lbl.id = "test";
$("#sec").append(lbl);
```

**CSS**

```
#test
{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

how to assign ID's to dynamic labels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `lbl.prop("id","test")` since you have initiated `lbl` as a jQuery element rather than a javascript/DOM element so it does not have the `id` property.

Answer (score 4):

need to use

```
var lbl = $("<label>", {
   id: 'test'
}).text('Welcome');

$("#sec").append(lbl);
```

or use attr

```
var lbl = $("<label>").text('Welcome');
lbl.attr('id', "test");
$("#sec").append(lbl);
```

Comment: +1 for the first method. Since the id was known before the element was created it makes sense to do it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically adding something is not that difficult.

See the code below :

**HTML:**

```
<label id ='lbl'>This is a label </label>
<button id ='btn'>Click</button>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#lbl").css("color","red");
    $("#lbl").css("fontSize","20px");
});
```

Working solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/baEWb/

**OR**

if you just want to use the `label` instead of any label id or class, then :

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("label").css("color","red");
    $("label").css("fontSize","20px");
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/baEWb/1/

Comment: @msg: U R Welcome  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
var lbl = $("<label id='test'>").text('Welcome');
$("#sec").append(lbl);
```

put "id='test'" in label tag